# How do i use grep command to find a text that includes a string like /usr/vm/data/?

Tags: linux, unix, grep

I want to use grep command to search for files containing the string "/usr/vm/data". For searching a normal string like "how are you", i know i can do:

`grep -inr "how are you" *`

to search recursively. But i am getting stuck in the cases where i need to search a path like "/usr/vm/data". I tried:
`grep -inr "\/usr\/vm\/data" directory1`

and also
`grep -inr "/usr/vm/data/" directory1`
but didn't get any success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your command works fine:

```
$ cat directory1/somefile
foo
bar
this line contains /usr/vm/data/
$ grep -inr "/usr/vm/data/" directory1
directory1/somefile:3:this line contains /usr/vm/data/
$
```

Perhaps your file is beyond a symlink which `grep` doesn't follow, or perhaps you don't have any matching files?

Answer (score 3):

Don't torture yourself, and it is a normal string (especially when you put it in quotes).

```
echo "/usr/vm/data Hello world" | grep -i "/usr/vm/data"
```